# Dealing with characters not supported by a font

Tags: website-design, design, web, font, style

I have a website which is used by people all around the world. I use a certain font which only just came to my attention does not support characters which my users have mentioned such as `ğ`, `ş` and `ı`.

As the font I use across my website does not have correct styling for these characters they look a bit odd. While this is not an issue for most users, there are a minority who this may be an issue for.

What could I do to make foreign characters appear more streamlined? Thanks.

Comment: Used in a lot of countries? [Have you Turkey Tested it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796986/what-is-the-turkey-test)?

Comment: While most of my users are from English speaking countries, I have users from countries which are not. Yes my code does support Turkey's formatting rules.

Comment: Many font makers would be happy to add characters needed by their users.  The answer is always no if you don't ask.

Comment: Many stop looking for a font when they find one with the right appeal and forget about the text and it's readers it should support. Always check the supported languages, special characters, legibility etc. Never choose aesthetics over readability unless it's intensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can simply use a different font, one that has all the characters.

2) You could include a fallback font that is somewhat similar to your main font, but includes more glyphs/characters. That way your main text is rendered with the original font and any characters not included in that font, should fallback to the other font. (That's how I assume it to work, correct me if 'm wrong)

Comment: Related: [Fallback fonts on special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters)

Answer (score 1):

All the characters should in included the font face for the font to render in other languages. Check the languages section in typekit(eg. font [Litaniarui](https://typekit.com/fonts/litaniarui)). If your font doesn't have all the languages then i would suggest to change the font of the body to a font which supports all the languages.